# If statement to find number of whitespaces in a string and detect regex according to the count

Tags: powershell

I need help on a PowerShell script to find the count of whitespaces in a string and identify the regex as per number of whitespaces in the string to ignore. This is for initializing the TFS branches which I pass as a Jenkins build parameter.

My code is:

```
git tfs branch -r | Out-File -FilePath ../Branches.txt

"List of remote branches of $reponame are below"

$text = Get-Content -Path ..\Branches.txt

foreach ($exp in $text) {
    [regex]$exp = "(\$[\/\w-]+\s[\/\w-]+\s[\/\w-]+)"
    [regex]$exp = "(\$[\/\w-]+\s[\/\w-]+\s[\/\w-]+\s[\/\w-]+\s[\/\w-]+)"
    [regex]$exp = "(\$[\/\w-]+)"
}

foreach ($line in $text) {
    $branch = $exp.Match($line).Value 

    "cloning $branch"

    git tfs branch --init $branch

    "done $branch"
}
```

Example strings are

```
$/External Websites/Main/ANI Mobile
$/Databases/Main/Business Intelligence/Database Projects/Sales Data Mart
$/Desktop/Main/BogusClassLibrary
```

Comment: Why are you assigning 'exp' three times in your foreach loop?

Comment: Could you also describe your basic idea? What git task do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you only want to remove the whitespaces? And / or Count them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about counting spaces, then you can use `-Split` and match against `^\s`:

```
$NumberOfSpaces = ($line -Split "( )" -Match "^\s").Count
```

However, if you must use regex, the following regex will capture all of your examples:

```
[regex]$exp = '\$([\/\w-]+(\s*))+'
```

If you want the matched text and sum of white spaces, you can use:

```
$MatchedText = $exp.Match($line).Value
$NumberOfWhiteSpaces = ($exp.Match($line).Groups[2].Captures.Length | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
```

**Explanation:**

- `.Groups[2]` lists each `\s*` capture. The `.Length` property lists how many spaces were found in each match. In your examples, the property returns 1 or 0.

If the number of consecutive spaces do not matter, the regex could be simpler: `\$[\/\w-\s]+`. This however, loses the capture groups.

Comment: This worked [regex]$exp = '\$([\/\w-]+(\s*))+\w+' Thank you so much !